# Trouble connecting to SQL Server Express with a C# AWS Lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-rds, sqlclient

I get the following error when trying to connect to my SQL Server Express RDS instance over AWS Lambda using `System.Data.SqlClient`:

> "errorType": "PlatformNotSupportedException",
>   "errorMessage": "Operation is not supported on this platform.",
>   "stackTrace": [
>   "at System.Runtime.InteropServices.OSPlatform.get_Windows()",
>   "at System.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SNITCPHandle.d__22.MoveNext()"
>   ]

I build the deploy package using [Amazon.Lambda.Tools](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/tree/master/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.Tools). Running the function and connecting to the database from local works fine, but fails when trying to run it on AWS Lambda.

Here is my `project.json`:

```
{
"version": "1.0.0-*",
"description": "AWS lambda Console Application",
"authors": [ "" ],
"packOptions": {
    "tags": [],
    "projectUrl": "",
    "licenseUrl": ""
},
"buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
},
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
    "type": "platform",
    "version": "1.0.0"
    },
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "9.0.1",
    "Amazon.Lambda.Core": "1.0.0*",
    "Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json": "1.0.1",
    "Amazon.Lambda.Tools": {
    "type": "build",
    "version": "1.0.0-preview1"
    },
    "Dapper": "1.50.2",
    "System.Data.SqlClient": "4.3.0"
},
"tools": {
    "Amazon.Lambda.Tools": "1.0.0-preview1"
}, 
"commands": {
    "AwsLambda": "run"
},
"frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
        "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Hi @torryt, pls how did you fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Had the same problem and for me just changing

```
"System.Data.SqlClient": "4.3.0"
```

to

```
"System.Data.SqlClient": "4.1.0"
```

worked for me. I did not have to change the NetCore.App dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

Explicitly add reference to

```
"System.Data.SqlClient": "4.1.0",
"System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation": "4.0.0"
```

solves the problem.

Comment: We had been pulling our hair out, over this issue. Finally for the heck of it, we tried your suggestion, and lo and behold, it actually worked! Super annoying issue, but thank god we found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to change

```
"System.Data.SqlClient": "4.3.0"
```

to

```
"System.Data.SqlClient": "4.1.0"
```

and change

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
    "type": "platform",
    "version": "1.0.0"
    },
```

to

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
    "type": "platform",
    "version": "1.0.1"
    },
```